# Thread: How to deploy a Pentaho report with subreports across multiple environments

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to create reports that I could deploy in different environments (test, production) and/or with different databases, without changing the prpt file.

So, I created some jndis, and pased the jndi name as a parameter to a xaction that in turn executed the query and passed the result to the prpt. It worked great.

Until I started using subreports.

I think there's no way to pass a result set to a subreport for each line of the main report.

It seems that If you use subreports, you have to define the  connection and the query inside the subreport.

Am I wrong? Has anyone tried this? What's the "proper" way to deploy a multi-tenant report with subreports, and pass the connection or jndi as a parameter?
(I'm open to drop the use of jndi if there's another way)

Thanks!

**Update:** There's a bug related to this in biserver 3.7 & 3.8 [link](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-5906)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope, the connection can be defined in the parent report. just make sure you specify it in the Query name setting of the subreport itself.

Comment: Codek, I'm sorry. I didn't explain myself. What I meant was that if you use an XAction to avoid specifying the connection inside the prpt (which is my intention since I'm using the report against 5+ databases at the same time), you still have to specify the connection in the subreport.

Comment: no you dont. just pass multiple data sets from the xaction to the report, and reference them as "external" data sets, and pass them to the subreport.  I've done this and it works fine.  It may be worth asking your question in the pentaho forum - it's a far better place to get Pentaho questions answered.

Comment: Thanks, Codek, that's what I did and nobody answered. I referenced both datasets in the report, but it seems the subreport prepared statement is not executing (if I pass it as a regular dataset, it executes allright). Do you happen to have a sample?

Comment: It's a bug that affects 3.7 and 3.8 [link](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-5906)

Comment: Doh! Oh well looks like lots of activity on it, hopefully will be fixed soon.  Handy to know..

Answer (score -1):

XActions precompute all datasets before the reporting engine has a chance to actually work with them. External datasets are precomputed without any information on your subreports, and therefore it will fail (unless you use several ugly tricks to use a calculated query-name as a lookup-key into the precomputed table-models).

Why don't you use JNDI, like everyone else? JDNI was designed to abstract connection information into a logical name. The connection is defined outside of the report, and the report just references the name.

Read more on my blog post named: "[Dont hardcode host names, use JDNI](http://www.sherito.org/2011/08/dont-hardcode-host-names-use-jndi.html)" (which probably describes the core of your problem ;) ).